# Knowledge Transfer To Services and Support Team

Tags: service, project-management

My team has created a suite of tools that are being transitioned to services and support (two separate teams).  We've been collaborating SDKs and techincal notes in places such as Sharepoint, OneNote, emails, TFS, wiki posts etc.  I'm interested in a professional way to hand off a collection of all these resources in one cohesive and concise format.  I'm looking for recommendations of methods to do so or possible linked examples that I can look at that do this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways to enact such a transfer is to create an internal Wiki site using free software such as [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). This site can be regularly updated with common questions and procedures.

The benefits of such an approach are:

- It is platform neutral for all clients (i.e., they just use a web browser).
- It is easy to update and maintain by multiple people, concurrently. Such updates can be performed on the fly, without having to take the site down or disable it in any way.
- It is a single repository of information, which works much better than multiple (potentially hard to find) disjoint repositories.
- It allows for an interactive format between content provider and content consumer (i.e., questions can be raised right on the Wiki site).
- It allows for a hierarchical presentation and enables easy searchability which fit well with how people try to find and consume information.
- It has the ability to track history and authorship of all edits.

There are also some drawbacks, so take them into account:

- Conversion from current information data formats would be necessary.
- Content specific security would be difficult to implement.
- Information quality can suffer, if people modify the site ad-hoc.
- Without proper review and central oversight, there is a potential for disinformation, misinformation, bias, and flame wars